# How to stop gridview from scrolling when a button click (fix gridview position)

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I have a gridview in my android project and need to stop from scrolling when a button click, how should I do this?
For example gridview is on FLING and user click on the button I want to stop gridview where it is and status of scrolling become IDLE.

P.S: I am using gridview inside a scrollview (please don't suggest to use something else like RecyclerView, for some reasons I can't).

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollview.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){ 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true; 
  }
});
```

This is disable your scrollview from scrolling. Add this in your button click.